# security access for groups symfony

Tags: security, symfony

Hi i have a group system and i'd like to add some security to it. 
Users can belong to multiple groups and id like to know the best way to authorize people to see the groups only if they are in it. If they aren't i want to redirect them to a another page, which is different according to the group. 
For now i created a service but i have to use it in every controller...
I've heard of multiple things but not sure if they are appropriate for my situation.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this depending on the approach/complexity. Here are a few:

1) Use Symfony ACLS. When a user is added to a particular group, you can use the symfony ACL system to grant them view access to that group, and then later check isGranted() against that group to see if they have view permissions.

2) Create a custom voter
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html#creating-a-custom-voter

3) If the number of groups is limited in number, you could even use Doctrine query filters to automatically add a where clause to all queries where the group_id is in a list of allowed groups for that user. You can bypass this for all admin users. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html

Comment: thanks. my number of groups is not limited . i think ill go with acls